# Kids Mode has disappeared after S4 Lollipop upgrade

Tags: updates, 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4

After upgrading the OS on my S4, Kids Mode suddenly disappeared today. Other S5 Galaxy users in my home can find Kids Mode in their Widgets but I cannot locate it anywhere. I upgraded 2 days ago and Kids Mode was accessed for the first time (since the update) today. The app requested an update, which I performed, then worked for about 1 minute before closing suddenly and disappearing completely. Does anyone know of Kids Mode being removed from the S4 or how to reinstall?